# Question on loopinbg - trying to find a prime number from a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am given a list of numbers and using python, I need to find the prime numbers in the list and print them out

I have tried several different things but can't quite get it to work. My latest attempt is below but that just returns all the numbers with the message saying that it is a prime number except for the last one.

```
    odd_numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29] 
    x = 0
    y = len(odd_numbers) - 1  

    # If given number is greater than 1 
    #if odd_numbers[x] > 2: 

    # Iterate from 2 to n / 2  
    for i in range(0, y):  
        # If num is divisible by any number between  
        # 2 and n / 2, it is not prime  
        if (odd_numbers[x] % 2) == 0: 
            break

        else: 
            pr_no =  odd_numbers[x]
            print(odd_numbers[x], "is a prime number") 
            x = x + 1

    else: 
       print(odd_numbers[x], "is not a prime number")
```

What it should do is print out:

2 is a prime number
3 is a prime number etc for all prime numbers in the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
odd_numbers = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29]

for x in odd_numbers:
    if x > 1:
        for y in range(2,x):
            if (x % y) == 0:
#               print(x,"is not a prime number")
#               print(y,"times",x//y,"is",x)
               break
        else:
            print(y,"is a prime number")
#    else:
#        print(x, "is not a prime number")
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you?